# python 2 not recognize "newline" for file stream

Tags: python-2.7

With Python 3.3, the following code works fine

```
import csv
with open(foname, "w", newline='') as outstream:
   csv.writer(outstream, delimiter =' ').writerows(
      [cell.value for cell in row]
      for row in ws.rows
   )
```

However, python-2 is unable to run that and says

```
   with open(foname, "w", newline='') as outstream:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What is the equivalent for previous versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with open(foname, 'wb') as outstream:`.  `newline` was a parameter added in Python 3.

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for Python 2 as:

> If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

Whereas for Python 3, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) says:

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''

Comment: Then, is the output the same?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The Python 2 `csv` module wasn't Unicode string-aware, so if you are writing Unicode strings you have to `.encode()` them yourself, or better yet, use the 3rd party [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) module.  Python 3's csv module is a vast improvement.